# Reactive Extensions for .Net with LINQ results

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am working on Hands-on-lab from Reactive Extensions for .Net. I use Form as shown in the example to understand how subscribe works. The following code is what I have:

```
   var txt = new TextBox();
        var frm = new Form
        {
            Controls = { txt }
        };

        var moves = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(frm, "MouseMove")
            .Select(e => e.EventArgs.Location);
        var input = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged")
            .Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text);

        var overFirstBisector = moves.Where(pos => pos.X == pos.Y);
        var firstSectorSubscription = overFirstBisector.Subscribe(pos =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse at First BiSector " + pos);
        });

        var movesSubscription = moves.Subscribe(evt =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse at: " + evt);
        });

        var inputSubscription = input.Subscribe(evt =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User wrote: " + evt);
        });
        using (new CompositeDisposable(firstSectorSubscription, movesSubsription, inputSubscription))
        {
            Application.Run(frm);
        }
```

When I ran the console app, it showed Mouse at:  , only when x=y, it shows Mouse at First BiSector. Since both moves subscription and firstSectorSubscription detect mouse moves under that condition, can someone explain why firstSectorSubscription was displayed over moves?

Comment: Per your code, it will only show `Mouse at First BiSector` if `pos.X==pos.Y`.  I'd imagine it doesn't when you first move the mouse, so it shows just `Mouse at`.  I'm not clear on why you expect otherwise?

Comment: Charles: Thanks for the quick comment. I did not write it in a clear way. Please see my edited version again

Comment: That makes a little more sense. I would expect it to show both, one after the other.  Are you *certain* they are the same?

Comment: @CharlesMager After I looked at the console output again, it does show both, Mouse at First BiSector first, Mouse at second. I am not sure what the order is based on though

Comment: Interesting, it is based on when you subscribe. If I move the code of movesSubscription ahead of firstBisectorSubscription, Mouse at will show first

Comment: That's what I'd expect. I'm not sure you can guarantee this in every case, but that's generally how it works.  [This MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac721f91-4dbc-40b8-a2b2-19f00998239f/order-of-subscriptions-order-of-observations?forum=rx) might give some insight.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesMager very good please post the answer with the Summary of the MSDN link.  +1 from me

Comment: Just a small thing with Rx and lambdas - you can replace `.Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text)` with `.Select(e => txt.Text)`. It's much cleaner.